# AngularJS : ng-disable not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to disable enable a button based on an input type value. Here is the Angular JS html code

```
<div ng-app>
    <form name="myForm" ng-controller="ctrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-required="true" />
        <span>{{name}}</span>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" ng-disabled="myForm.name.$pristine" />
    </form>
</div>
```

And the controller code:

```
function ctrl($scope){
    $scope.name = "hello";
}
```

But the button is not getting disabled no matter what.

Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rE8p9/)

**NOTE:** I want the button to be disabled only when text box doesn't have any value and vice versa

Comment: ng-disabled="!name" also works fine

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" ng-disabled="name==undefined || name==''" />
```

Hope it helps.....................

Answer (score 6):

You need  and `name` on the input to work.

`<input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-required="true" name='myName' ng-model='myName'/>`

See my fiddle here

http://jsfiddle.net/cmyworld/6Zjd3/1/

Comment: *It's not working.*In the demo it seems to be disabled whether the input text has value or not. I was trying to make it disabled when no data in textbox and vice versa

Comment: I applied the directives on submit not input text box.

Comment: This works only initially. If i input the text and den delete it doesn't disable the button

Comment: Pristine, means that the control has not been touched, empty or otherwise. you can use required attribute on the html and check for `myForm.name.$error.required`. See developer api for form https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.15/docs/guide/forms

Answer (score 2):

```
    <div ng-app>
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-required="true" />
    <span>{{name}}</span>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" ng-disabled="{{myForm.name.$pristine}}" />
</form>
```

Replace:

```
ng-disabled="myForm.name.$pristine"
```

With:

```
ng-disabled="{{myForm.name.$pristine}}"
```

Comment: This solved my problem, even when everybody is saying to remove the brackets inside angular directives

Answer (score 1):

`myForm.name` refers to the first control with the `name` attribute set to "name". Since you don't have one, it refers to the forms `name` attribute itself, returning "myForm". `"myForm".$pristine` is undefined, so `ng-disabled=undefined` won't work.

As the others mentioned, you need to add the `name="name"` attribute to the control it should refer to.

```
<input type="text" name="name" ng-model="name" ng-required="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, maybe it will work ...

```
< input type="search" ng-required="true" placeholder="username to find" ng-model="username" />
< input type="submit" value="search" ng-disabled="!username" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it for you

you were referring to `name` which didn't existed as it's input id/name

```
<input id="name" name="name" type="text" ng-model="name" ng-required="true" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rE8p9/1/

Answer (score 0):

add 'name' attribute to input, it's solve the problem

```
<div ng-app>
 <form name="form" ng-controller="ctrl">
   <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="name" ng-required="true" />
   <span>{{name}}</span>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" ng-disabled="form.name.$pristine" />
 </form>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle.net/ariel_ma/GYt3y/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/ariel_ma/GYt3y/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Changed your code.

```
  <div ng-app> <form name="myForm" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-required="true" />
 <span>{{name}}</span>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" name='myName' ng-model='name' ng-disabled="!myForm.$pristine" /> </form> </div>
```

(Notice the negation ).

You can even use "myForm.$invalid instead".
ng-disabled expects an bool value/ expression returns bool.

In other words it reads Boolean value.